# Why no ios.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

Why is there a separate android stack exchange site but not iOS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iOS, Mac OS X and other Apple-related, non-programming questions do have an SE site for them: [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: ah that makes sense, I assumed the android site was for programming android not non-programming stuff.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It hasen't been proposed at area51, if you feel there should be, go propose it at http://area51.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you'd want the site to do. If it were programming related (developing for ios) then [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be your site.

Otherwise, the [Apple stackexchange site](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) is likely what you want...particularly the [IOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag